Resizable System Logs Container in flutter
I'm working on implementing a system logs feature in my Flutter application, and I want to achieve a user interface similar to the one shown in the image below. and how to make resizable container for displaying system logs.
System Logs
(https://protonvpn.com/support/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/AsusWRT-OpenVPN-version.png)
System logs same in image

Maybe you can try this package to achieve that flutter_box_transform and it has a good documentation
